# Заполнить массив данной последовательностью

Tags: c++

Дана последовательность `1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 ...`
Нужно заполнить ею линейный массив.
Знаю, как реализовать последовательность:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        cout << " " << i;
```

Но как заполнить этими числами линейный массив? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так же:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= cnt; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            a[k++] = i;
```